# How to initialize seed data from another DbContext

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

My project has 2 DbContext (in 2 Entity Framework project): `CoreDbContext` and `Module1DbContext`

In `CoreDbContext` I have 1 table named `SystemStatus`. So is it possible to insert seed data to this table from `Module1DbContext`? I tried to pass CoreDbContext to Seed method in Module1DbContext but it did work.

Comment: Is this EF Core or EF 6? For EF Core, see [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/29/implementing-seeding-custom-conventions-and-interceptors-in-ef-core-1-0/)

Comment: This is EF 6, bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Just new up the other context and do what you need. If the CoreDbContext is in another project you will need to reference it.

```
protected override void Seed(Module1DbContext context)
{
    // get some data from the current context you want to use for seeding
    var someItemFromM1 = context.FooBar.FirstOrDefault(fb => fb.Id == myID);
    if (someDataFromM1 != null)
    {
        using (var coreContext = new CoreDbContext())
        {
            // Using AddOrUpdate which is designed for seeding, but you could just use standard update code
            coreContext.SystemStatuses.AddOrUpdate(
                ss => ss.Code,  // Unique field to check so duplicate not added
                new SystemStatus
                {
                    Code = someItemFromM1.Code,
                    Description = someItemFromM1.Description
                });
            coreContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Steve! I didn't think about that, haha